# How would I assign the result of an sql query to a variable using mysql procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table in mysql with n rows and columns

```
col1 col2
a     b
c     d
```

...

Using mysql procedures, how would I get all the rows into 1 varchar variable?

```
DECLARE var varchar(4096);
SET var = <select * from table>
```

The value of var should be "a b\nc d\n...."

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do:

```
select var := group_concat(col1, ' ', col2 separator '
')
from table;
```

Seems a bit strange, but it will do what you want.

EDIT:

You can also do:

```
select var := group_concat(col1, ' ', col2 separator '\n')
from table;
```

Comment: Can you please explain. What is 'separator'? Are you sure about the syntax? There are 2 quotes after separator - one of them is on a newline.

Comment: @user674669 . . . Usually `\n` means a new line.  That is an easy way to put one in, without worrying about escaping things.  `separator` is a keyword for `group_concat()`.